# Converting form to a Nested Json with Angular - Ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a nested Json model class and a form is associated to it. On submitting the form I am not getting the nested json structure.

Tried [{ngModel}] = "service.clientObject.address.address1", still I am not getting the nested json structure after submitting the form

### My HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="createClient(form)" #form="ngForm" 
  autocomplete="off">
<div class="form-group mb-2">
   <label class="label-style label-top"><b>Address:</b> </label>
   <div>
    <div class="ml-md-3 mb-1"><input name="address1" placeholder="Address 
        Line1" #address1=ngModel              
          [(ngModel)]="service.clientObject.address.address1"
           class="form-control input-length">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

---

### Constructor in Component.ts

```
 import { ClientsServiceService } from 'src/app/clients-service.service';

 //and inside my component class I have constructor like this
  constructor(private service: ClientsServiceService) {}
```

---

### Service class

```
import { CreateClient } from 'src/app/shared/models/createClient.model';

export class ClientsServiceService {
 clientObject: CreateClient;
 constructor() {
   this.clientObject = new CreateClient();
  }}
```

---

### Model class

```
// client class
import { Address } from './address.model';
export class CreateClient {
  address: Address;}

//Address Class
 export class Address{
address1: string;
address2: string;
country: string;
state: string;
zipcode: string;}
```

Now after submitting the form expecting

```
{
  Address:{address1:"Some address"}
}
```

### But getting

```
 {address1:"Some address"}
```

Comment: You have a class called `Address`, yes, but where did that property` Address` from `{
  Address:{address1:"Some address"}
}` come from?

Comment: Yes Address is my class name and I have imported that class in my client model. So I am expecting {
  Address:{address1:"Some address"}
}  from form on submit

If I want a structure as above what should I do?

Comment: Does that answered your question?

Comment: That's just a simple misunderstanding. What you will obtain if you log a form is a JSON with form names as keys(`name="address1"`) and its corresponding values. What you are expecting is the actual object. Use a variable of the `Address` class and use it in `ngModel`.

Comment: @sreenivas yes it does, thanks for clarifying! I believe Arcteezy has sufficiently answered your problem. Are you still having issues though?

Comment: My aim is to pass that form object as such to an API if it is properly formed there. As suggested I have changed the ngModel to address object .. still I am not getting a header for that json

Comment: I have extra fields in the form which are of client model and for client address in that form I need to create a address header under the client json. So I used Client model object for some values and address object for other values in the form. Is that correct?... Even i used like this I didn't get address fields under a header "Address"... let me know how to group certain values in the form under some header